# Unity Facebook SDK appInvite not showing notifications

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-app-invites

I'm implementing a game which features inviting your Facebook friends to your app using the Facebook SDK.

The code I'm using is:

```
FB.Mobile.AppInvite (new System.Uri(appLink), null, callback);
```

The app link is the proper one setup in the facebook page of the app.

The problem is this: the user doesn't receive a notification inside the FB app to install my game. Instead, you have to go to the Facebook App -> Apps -> App invites and it appears there. In the Facebook docs it says the user should receive a notification to invite. 
What is the issue here?

PS: the app is not live yet, but the friends that are invited are set as testers.

Comment: Facebook sends notifications if they think the user wants it. You can't control it

Comment: I beg to differ. This link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview says otherwise. To quote: "People receive a Facebook notification for each invite sent to them."

Comment: @WizKid Could you post a reference?